# Dell Open Manage physical disk failure predicted

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, dell-poweredge, drive-failure, dell-openmanage

I've installed the Open Manage Server Administrator on my Dell T100 to monitor RAID Controller and disks. From the Physical Controller report web page I see a table listing the two disks I have but under the column "Failure Predicted" I see the capacity in GB! is it an error or what?

If I expand the details for the also here I can read the disk capacity both in the capacity field but also in the Failure Predicted!

Server: DELL T100;
OS: Windows 2008 R2 Web Edition with IIS7 and an instance of SQL Server web edition;
Raid controller: SAS 6/iR;
Hard Disk: Seagate ST500NM0011;
Dell OpenManage Software: Version 6.5.0;

Comment: have you tried using a different browser, different OMSA version, different screen resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you attempted to run the command from the console of the device (ie. over the drac via ssh or through the console via activex plugin and java console)?

I'm not 100% on the command from a windows/rdp terminal, but you can run OpenManage commands via command line in Linux like this:

```
omreport storage pdisk controller=0
```

Of course, this depends on your version of OpenManage. Also, it seems there is a command like this:

```
omreport storage arrays
```

Also, probably the best tool, is the `-?`:

```
omreport -?

omreport storage -?
```

and so forth. Check the documentation for your particular version. This will also avoid the potential for misalignment of screen data. Here's what this would generally look like:

```
~]# omreport storage pdisk controller=0
List of Physical Disks on Controller PERC 6/i Integrated (Embedded)

Controller PERC 6/i Integrated (Embedded)
ID                              : 0:0:0
Status                          : Ok
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:0:0
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Not Applicable
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : No
Revision                        : HT64
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Not Applicable
Encryption Capable              : No
Encrypted                       : Not Applicable
Progress                        : Not Applicable
Mirror Set ID                   : Not Applicable
Capacity                        : 136.13 GB (146163105792 bytes)
Used RAID Disk Space            : 136.13 GB (146163105792 bytes)
Available RAID Disk Space       : 0.00 GB (0 bytes)
Hot Spare                       : No
Vendor ID                       : DELL(tm)
Product ID                      : ST9146852SS
Serial No.                      : 6TB1B4BC
Part Number                     : CN0X162K7262213D01WFA01
Negotiated Speed                : Not Available
Capable Speed                   : Not Available
PCIe Negotiated Link Width      : Not Applicable
PCIe Maximum Link Width         : Not Applicable
Sector Size                     : 512B
Device Write Cache              : Not Applicable
Manufacture Day                 : 03
Manufacture Week                : 11
Manufacture Year                : 2011
SAS Address                     : 5000C50039717D01
Form Factor                     : Not Available
Sub Vendor                      : Not Available
```

So, this would circumvent any issues with your browser, though it may have some screen wrapping issues depending on the size of your command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alignment issue of the columns, not sure what causes this.  All responses from Bus Prtocol down should be shifted down one row.

Answer (score -1):

the fact that the HD has a Predictive Failure has nothing to do with the size, it's just the Hard Drive is going to fail, you just need to change the HD with the predictive failure, contact Dell Tech Support and they will guide you in the process of solving the issue.

Regards,

Comment: You did not read the actual post at all, did you?